# Any way to remove overlapping textures?

Tags: 3d, coloring, mathematica

I have used Graphics3D to create two cubes in 3d, and the faces of one line up with the faces of another. This creates a strange overlapping effect which glitches between the two colors chosen for each cube. Is there any way to remove one or both of the textures in this overlapped space? Or any way to stop the flashing between the two textures?

Comment: As this is a software related question it is inappropriate for this site. I would suggest asking this in a mathematica-related forum/stack.

Comment: @Matt Roberts This site is not especialy a bad site for this sort of questions that are common to any graphical software (there is Mathematica sub-site in Stack Exchange, but you will not necessarily meet people there that have had this type of problem). An issue remain : without seeing the type of "conflict" generated by the neigboring textures, it is hard to give any advice. You should include an screen copy if possible.

Comment: Why don't you provide a screen copy of this effect  ?